# Execute code when breakpoint is hit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

In the Immediate window, I can execute a line of code. I can also set a breakpoint at a particular point so that when the breakpoint is hit, the program stops and I can run my line of code in the Immediate window. Is there any way (extensions included) to do this automatically?

Comment: Have you tried using debug.print?

Comment: So you want automated debugging?!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just modify the program?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but you can print stuff to Debug Output window using the 'When Hit' dialog. It's pretty flexible, and combines well with conditional breakpoints.

Comment: Maybe [#if DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) is what you want?

Comment: I am aware of the ability to print code when hitting the breakpoint, and yes it is very useful - what I would like is to be able to execute arbitrary code when a breakpoint is hit, so that I can experiment *without recompiling* every time. Perhaps I will have to look at writing an extension.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

More or less. You can rightclick any breakpoint and select "Actions..." (VS 2017, read on for older versions)

The only option in there is to print a message, which is usually sufficient, but you can run arbitrary code in there. For example: `{Console.WriteLine("Hello World")}`

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2017 Actions breakpoint]

In older versions of Visual Studio, the option is available by rightclicking and choosing "When Hit...":

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio When-Hit breakpoint]

This will output:

> Hello World
>   Expression has been evaluated and has no value

This means you can call arbitrary methods. Any other side effects will carry to your running application. I sometimes use it to temporarily patch a problem with the code without restarting the 64-bit application.

Keep in mind that this is exceptionally slow compared to normal program execution however.

Comment: Would you mind pasting the text from the dialog? I can't view the imgur image through my work's lousy filter. Thanks! (I'm assuming it is any code expression, which would make sense)

Comment: @AlexG I did put the text as the image description, but I'll edit it to appear in the post.

Comment: Oh I see, I think the alt-text is slightly different to the output ("Hallo" vs "Hello World") but I get it. Thanks :)

Comment: Not availabile in VS2017

Comment: @JamesWierzba It is available, but called "Actions..." in VS2017

Answer (score 2):

The answer for Visual Studio 2017 is similar to Thorarin's answer, but some UI components have changed.

In visual studio 2017, the menu item you are looking for is "Actions".

Right click breakpoint, and select "Actions", and then place your code you wish to execute within brackets `{ .. code to execute .. }` in the "Log a message to output window" field.