# Execute C# code with side effects on breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

I would like to use a breakpoint to execute code in Visual Studio 2017 and have the side effects of that code affect the program. It appears from [Execute code when breakpoint is hit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152042/execute-code-when-breakpoint-is-hit) that this was possible in a past version of Visual Studio.

But consider the code below.

```
    int Counter = 0;

    public bool Increment()
    {
        Counter++;
        return false;
    }
    public void PrintNumbers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Iteration {i}");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Counter: " + Counter);
    }
```

I have set a breakpoint on the line that runs the "Iteration" as follows:

[image: breakpoint setting]

When this runs, it produces the following output:

Iteration 0
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Counter: 0

This is a true technological marvel! Visual Studio does run the code -- if I change the "return false" in Increment() to "return true," the breakpoint will be hit. But it magically avoids side effects. That's great! But I want side effects. In other words, I really want an action option besides "log a message to output windows" that allows execution of code with side effects. Is there any way around this Visual Studio feature?

You might be wondering why I want to do this. I would like to make a conditional breakpoint dependent on another conditional breakpoint having been passed. (For example, I know that the Knight is talking funny after meeting the Princess, so I want to put a breakpoint on KnightTalks() that stops only if some code in KnightMeetsPrincess() has executed. I run into situations this all the time and get annoyed when I have to disable the KnightTalks breakpoint and reenable it after KnightMeetsPrincess, especially when there is a longer chain of events.) Based on [Conditional breakpoint depends on other breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342127/conditional-breakpoint-depends-on-other-breakpoint), I think there is no built-in way to do this. But I could do something like it if I could execute arbitrary code -- for example, if I could set and get a pseudovariable. Or one could use code like the following:

```
public static class Bookmark
{
    static Dictionary<string, int> HitCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public static bool Set(string s)
    {
        if (!HitCounts.ContainsKey(s))
            HitCounts[s] = 1;
        else
            HitCounts[s]++;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool Set(string s, bool condition)
    {
        if (condition)
            Set(s);
        return false;
    }

    public static bool Get(string s)
    {
        return HitCounts.ContainsKey(s);
    }
}
```

The idea of this code was that I would put a conditional breakpoint on KnightMeetsPrincess that called Bookmark.Set("KnightMeetsPrincess") and then on KnightTalks, a separate conditional breakpoint called Bookmark.Get("KnightMeetsPrincess"). Alas, this doesn't work because the code executes, but without side effects.

Any workarounds?